# GeoWebCache tiles with specific scales

Tags: openlayers-2, geowebcache

Is it possible to generate some tiles by GeoWebCache with specific scales eg.
1 000 000 , 500 000 etc. By default they are eg. 611.4962261962891, 305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226, 76.43702827453613 what is very confusing for me actually.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's not possible. In the most recent version GWC (starting from [1.3 RC1](https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/tree/1.3-RC1)) will simply throw an error while before it used to rely the request to the upstream WMS (without caching the response).

The reason is that GWC align tiles to Google Maps as stated in this email:

http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/GeoWebCache-GeoServer-EPSG-900913-tp6127128p6127129.html

This is the commit that actually changed the the behaviour from transparent to exception-throwing (and caught me off guard):

https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/commit/ff2c876fa35b25cc9bebfdfd1da4d0ffe65f2d2d

Comment: @alex you're welcome. I see you're new and I'd like to remember you that if you found the answer useful you should vote for it and, if it is the case, accept it.